# Anyway vs Anyways and Beside vs Besides

Tags: word-usage

I hope there's someone who can use these words for me in proper sentences.

**Thanks**

Answer (score 1):

Anyway: adverb
**used to confirm or support a point or idea just mentioned.**

Anyways: adverb
**nonstandard form of anyway.**

Beside: preposition
**at the side of; next to.**

Besides: preposition
**in addition to; apart from.**